# Need help to concatinate Dictionary output to a string for checking web pages

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am web scraping to get ticker ids for another program I plan to run and save them to a csv. However, they are saved in the format of `['tickerid']`.

The code I am using to scrape financial data is essentially:

```
url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/'+result[row]+'.l?p='+result[row]+'.l'
```

However, this doesn't work because `result[row]` will come out as:

```
https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/'['TSCO']'.l?p='['TSCO']'.l
```

Instead of:

```
https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/TSCO.l?p=TSCO.l
```

How can I remove the `['']` so that I can iterate through my dictionary of tickers?

My result output currently looks like this:

```
 'Ticker': 'Ticker', "['100D']": "['100D']", "['100H']": "['100H']", "['1GIS']": "['1GIS']", "['1MCS']": "['1MCS']", "['1PAS']": "['1PAS']", "['2AAP']": "['2AAP']", "['2AMZ']": "['2AMZ']", "['2CIT']": "['2CIT']", "['2CRM']": "['2CRM']", "['2FB']": "['2FB']", "['2GOO']": "['2GOO']", "['2GS']": "['2GS']", "['2JPM']"
```

Comment: Your output example is not a valid expression. Please show how you get `result`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it to `result[row][2:-2]`.

Comment: Ive added some of the output its actually a dictionary (i mistakenly put list) Apologies for that.

Comment: I see, what I think you might want to try then is `result[row][2:-2]`. Let me know if it still doesn't work.

Comment: Emma you appear to be a genius! It Appears to work so thank you so much.

Comment: Not a problem :)